# Javascript Prototype make function that returns value from array

Tags: javascript, prototype

I recently started to learn prototype and wanted to ask if there is some way to make something like this but in working shape, if I use `this.lang[array][keys][here]` or something similar it would return value from `this.defaults.translations` reason behind this is, I wan't to make lang function in which it will check if given index exists and if no then it will fallback on default language.

```
function Test() {
   this.output();
}

Test.prototype.defaults = {
   lang: 'en',
   translations: {
      en: {
         something: [
            'Something here'
         ]
      }
   }
};

Test.prototype.lang = function() {
    return this.defaults.translations[this.defaults.lang];
};

Test.prototype.output = function() {
   return this.lang['something'][0];
};

var test = new Test();
```

**UPDATED:**
Found solution, check my answer below!

Comment: `function Test() { this.output();}`  is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution, there is what I did to manage what I wanted.

```js
function Test() {}

Test.prototype.defaults = {
   lang: 'en_GB',
   fallbackLang: 'en_US',
   translations: {
      en_US: {
         strings: [
            'Color',
            'Chips'
         ]
      },
      en_GB: {
         strings: [
            'Colour',
            'Crisps'
         ]
      }
   }
};

Test.prototype.splitToArray = function(array, string) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(string.split('.'), function(key) {
        if (typeof array !== "undefined") {
            array = array[key];
        }
    });

    return array;
};

Test.prototype.__ = function (key) {
    var self = this,
        translation = this.splitToArray(self.defaults.translations[self.defaults.lang], key);

    if (typeof translation === "undefined") {
        // Set to fallback language if translation is not found
        translation = this.splitToArray(self.defaults.translations[self.defaults.fallbackLang], key);

        if (typeof translation === "undefined") {
            // return given key if translation is not found
            return key;
        }
    }

    return translation;
};

console.log(new Test().__('strings.0'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `lang` (or use a getter).

```js
function Test() {}
Test.prototype.defaults = {
  lang: 'en',
  translations: {
    en: {
      something: [
        'Something here'
      ]
    }
  }
};
Test.prototype.lang = function() {
  return this.defaults.translations[this.defaults.lang];
};
Test.prototype.output = function() {
  return this.lang()['something'][0];
};
console.log(new Test().output()); // 'Something here'
```

Comment: I updated my question, hope it will help to understand what I exactly wanted to achieve.

Comment: @allyfai No, I don't understand what are `my, arguments, provided` and what `lang` is supposed to return and what's wrong with the code you provided.

Comment: you know, if you provide multiple arguments, by example lang('this', 'function', 'has', 'multiple', 'arguments'); you can get all arguments in method with this magic variable called 'arguments'
function lang() { console.log(arguments) }, basically what I wan't to achieve is that my lang function checks is provided arguments are existing keys in current language, and if no then fallback to default language, I don't know how else I can explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a getter:

```
Test.prototype.getLang = function getLang(lang) { 
  return this[lang] || someDefaultLang;
};

var test = new Test();
console.log(test.getLang("en"));
```

If you want to be fancier and don't need to support old IE you can alternately do this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Test.prototype, "lang", {
  get: function(lang) {
    return this[lang] || someDefaultLang;
  }
});

console.log(test.en);
```

works in IE 9+

Comment: I updated my question, hope it will help to understand what I exactly wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You just do it like this;

```js
function Test() {};

Test.prototype.defaults = {
   lang: 'en',
   translations: {
      en: {
         something: [
            'Something here'
         ]
      }
   }
};

Test.prototype.lang = function() {
    return this.defaults.translations[this.defaults.lang];
};

Test.prototype.output = function() {
   return this.lang();
};

var test = new Test();

console.log(test.output());
```

Comment: I updated my question, hope it will help to understand what I exactly wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It is very much depends on your future needs, but one other option is using static properties:

```js
 function Test() {
    }

    Test.defaults = {
       lang: 'en',
       translations: {
          en: {
             something: [
                'Something here'
             ]
          }
       }
    };

    Test.prototype.lang = function() {
        return Test.defaults.translations[Test.defaults.lang];
    };

    Test.prototype.output = function() {
       return this.lang()['something'][0];
    };

    var test = new Test();
    alert(test.output());
```

Comment: I updated my question, hope it will help to understand what I exactly wanted to achieve.